# can't reduce space between figure and text

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, text, white-space

I've tried different methods but I can't figure out how to reduce the space between the figure and the text. 
Globally I have this:

```
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}
```

I've found these looking for answers and tried them. Now there are some figures that do not cause any problem, and then there are others that leaves a big white space between them and the text. This is what it looks like:

[image]

How can I remove once and for all the whitespaces?

Comment: Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem you describe the following is just a guess: It seems as if your document is using `\flushbottom` (either explicitly or through the documentclass you are using). Using `\raggedbottom` might fix the white space, but keep in mind, that the position of the last line of text won't  necessarily  be identical on every page.

Comment: And stop using [H] or [h].  [htp] will generally be better.

Comment: @JohnKormylo why? What is the difference?

Comment: [H} converts the figure into a minipage.  [h] means "here if possible, or wait until the next \clearpage" since no other option is provided.  [htp] means "here if possible, the top of the next page if not, or in a page with a bunch of the figures if they start backing up in the queue."   I might add that [h!] is converted to [htp] automatically.  It means "I don't know what I am doing so ignore me."